# Flutter: Outline input border

Tags: dart, flutter, textfield

I was trying to build a border for my text field like:

```
return TextField(
  ...
 border: OutlineInputBorder(
  borderSide: BorderSide(
   color: Colors.red, 
    width: 5.0),
    )
  )
)
```

But it always return a black border with 1.0 as width. 
The only way that I found to change the color was to create a ThemeData where I specify the hint color, but I could not find a way to change my width.

Comment: Not exactly answer to your question but just to add border to TextField this works:
`TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(),),),);`
More at: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/OutlineInputBorder-class.html

Answer (score 231, accepted):

What your looking for is - `enabledBorder` property of `InputDecoration`.

If you want to Change Border on focus use - `focusedBorder`

```dart
    TextField(
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.greenAccent, width: 5.0),
            ),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 5.0),
            ),
            hintText: 'Mobile Number',
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: I'm not able to find `focusedBorder` property in `InputDecoration`

Comment: @AshutoshSagar  what version of flutter you are running.?

Comment: v1.0.0 which is the stable one

Answer (score 21):

For others coming here who just want a `TextField` with a border all around it:

```dart
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 9):

You can change the outlined variant of `TextField` or `TextFormField` globally by overriding the `ThemeData` at the top level:

```
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
  ),
)
```

### [Live Demo](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e9f2dbe38ae4d68b56f9a534b73cdd02&null_safety=true)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this one and it is working for me.

```
InputDecoration(
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius:
          BorderRadius.circular(16),
      borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2.5),
    ),
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius:
          BorderRadius.circular(16),
      borderSide: const BorderSide(color:Colors.black, width: 1.5),
    ),
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 1):

- for only one TextField:

  ```
  const TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(), 
        labelText: 'First Name'),
  ),
  ```
- for all app TextFields in **ThemeData** widget:

**inputDecorationTheme:
const InputDecorationTheme(border: OutlineInputBorder()),**

then use in all pages:

```
  const TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'First Name'),
  ),
```