# How to change color of outline border?

Tags: flutter, colors

Im trying to change the color of my outline border . When focus on it ,it get a default color I think and I wanna change that to black but dont now how to doing that .

This is my widget :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            
            child: TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration( hintText: 'Send a message',border: OutlineInputBorder( borderRadius:
              const BorderRadius.all(
                const Radius.circular(40.0),
              ),

              ),

              ),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _enteredMessage = value;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            color: Colors.black,
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.send,
            ),
            onPressed: _enteredMessage.trim().isEmpty ? null : _sendMessage,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So when user try to inout some text the radius should be black .Hope anyone can help thanks .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Outline input border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54143526/flutter-outline-input-border)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InputDecoration` has many attributes for different situations such as errorBorder,
focusedBorder,
focusedErrorBorder,
disabledBorder,
enabledBorder,
border,

I think what you need here, you can achieve it by `focusedBorder`

```
focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                const Radius.circular(40.0),
              ),
              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.black),
            ),
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Why did you change the best response? Was there a problem with my response?

Comment: No it wasnt but the other user was 3 minutes before you ,its just fair he have the same answer in my opinion.

Comment: No I answered 2 mins before the other user :) That's ok, no problem

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your input decoration

```
focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
    const Radius.circular(40.0),
 ),
 borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
),
```